# Error in IronPython Command Line Compiler

Tags: ironpython

AttributeError: attribute "CompilerSink" of "namespace#" object is read-only

Comment: I think a little more information might be helpful!

Comment: I dont think there is anything more to add that could be helpful really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you're using a version of pyc.py against a version of IronPython for which it is not intended.  The latest versions of IronPython include pyc.py in the Tools\Scripts directory of the installation dir.

Comment: Thank you Dino. Though now I'm getting another in some situations